# Microsoft Speech.Synthesis Async speech not Asynchronous

Tags: vb.net, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Good evening.  I'm trying to do a reverb effect using a simple delay, but code does not continue to execute despite using the SpeakAsync Method.

I could find very little documentation on this issue anywhere, so I'd greatly appreciate any tips one can give.  Thank you for your time!
I'm using System.Speech version 4.0.0 in Visual Studio 2017.
I'm targeting runtime 4.5.2

```
Imports System.Speech.Synthesis
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Module Module1

Sub main()
    Dim SpeechString As String = "This is a test phrase, there are many 
like it, but this one is mine."
    Call OutSpeech(1, 100, SpeechString)

End Sub


Sub OutSpeech(SpeechRate As Integer, SpeechVolume As Integer, SpeechText As String)
    Dim SpeechHolder As New SpeechSynthesizer

    SpeechHolder.Rate = SpeechRate
    SpeechHolder.Volume = SpeechVolume
    SpeechHolder.SpeakAsync(SpeechText)
    Thread.Sleep(100)
    SpeechHolder.SpeakAsync(SpeechText)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: BTW, in your question you are referencing `Microsoft Speech`, but your code uses `System.Speech`. Those are two different assemblies, you should be more specific about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `SpeechHolder.SpeakAsync(SpeechText)` sequentially will just queue the output and the Speech(es) won't overlap.

A reverb effect is a sort of echo effect where fast waves are merged together in a short a delay. So, to have a reverb-like effect, generate two or more identical sounds with a delay between each of them.

The `Reverb()` method will call twice `OutSpeech()`, setting an adeguate delay (100ms seems appropriate to get the result).

```
Sub Reverb()
  Dim Delay As Integer = 100
  Dim SpeechString As String = "This is a test phrase, there are many like it, but this one is mine."
  OutSpeech(1, 100, Delay, SpeechString)
  OutSpeech(1, 100, Delay, SpeechString)

End Sub
```

The `OutSpeech()` method becomes an async one, so the calls will overlap when creating a new Synthetizer.
Two Tasks are created. One to set the Delay, and one to (a)wait while the synthetizer is "speaking", testing `SpeechHolder.State`.

```
Async Sub OutSpeech(SpeechRate As Integer, SpeechVolume As Integer, Delay As Integer, SpeechText As String)
    Using SpeechHolder As SpeechSynthesizer = New SpeechSynthesizer
        SpeechHolder.Rate = SpeechRate
        SpeechHolder.Volume = SpeechVolume

        Await Task.Run(Async Function() As Task(Of Boolean)
                       SpeechHolder.SpeakAsync(SpeechText)
                       Await Task.Delay(Delay)
                       Await Task.Run(Sub()
                                          While SpeechHolder.State = SynthesizerState.Speaking
                                          End While
                                      End Sub)
                       Return True
                   End Function)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't put the `SpeechSynthesizer` in a `using` block because it is disposed before the sound has a chance to play.

Comment: @Crowcoder  You missed `Await Task.Run(Sub() While (...)`

Comment: I'm talking about the "You might also ...  SpeechHolder.Dispose() isn't needed anymore " edit. Maybe I misunderstand but if I misunderstand then OP might too.

Comment: @Crowcoder Do you mean I should be more explicit in describing why is not needed anymore?

Comment: Did you actually try it from within a `using` block? I did, and it doesn't work. You would need to handle the `SpeakCompleted` event to dispose the synthesizer.

Comment: @Crowcode  Yes, of course I've tested it. Did you comment out just that line (`SpeechHolder.Dispose()`) or something else?

Comment: I didn't try your code, I was talking about mine. I see now what you mean, how you are using the state of the synthesizer in a `while`. If you don't read carefully (like me) then you can misunderstand what you mean by `Using` example.

Comment: @Crowcoder  Allright, I will take your advice and make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Digging into `System.Speech.dll` it appears to queue speak operations. So even though the speech will begin asynchronously, it will only play one at a time.

This is as far as I went into the decompiled assembly before I figured this is what must be going on:

```
private void AddSpeakParameters(VoiceSynthesis.Parameters param)
{
    lock (this._pendingSpeakQueue)
    {
        this._pendingSpeakQueue.Enqueue(param);
        if (this._pendingSpeakQueue.Count == 1)
        {
            this._evtPendingSpeak.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use multiple instances of `SpeechSynthesizer` to play sounds at the same time or offset by your sleep.